# Get node based on another node value with whitespaces on it

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to get the value of "state" when the node "name" is equal for example to "This is A" based on the XML below:

```
<xml>

<event>
    <name>This is A</name>
    <state>OK</state>
</event>
<event>
    <name>This is B</name>
    <state>KO</state>
</event>

</xml>
```

Doing something like `//event[name="This is A"]/state.text()` doesn't work... How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `text()` function should be separated from `state` using a slash, not a period:

```
//event[name="This is A"]/state/text()
```

Comment: Using xmllint from linux terminal I get syntactic error near ( and using QXMLEdit doesn't show anything as result of that xpath expresion. Also, removing the last part "/text()" just to test, I get "xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed" because of the "This is A" as it seems

Comment: @user712533:  This seems to work for me (note the quotes around the XPath expression):  `xmllint --xpath '//event[name="This is A"]/state/text()' x.xml`